# php regex get div content

Tags: php, regex

why my code not working

my **php** code

```
preg_match('@<div id="table-1"(.*?)></div>@si', $data, $table);
```

the **div** that i want to get the content

```
<div id="table-1" aria-labelledby="id-1" class="tabs-panel widget-content" role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
<!-- content -->
</div>
```

Comment: It's better to use an HTML parser like `DOMDocument` than try to parse HTML with a regexp

Comment: There's no `></div>` in the data, because `>` is on a different line from `</div>`

Comment: the content have a table and i want to use it but the code not working

Comment: @Barmar can u edt please

Comment: _the content have a table and i want to use it but the code not working_ Which comment is that in response to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also think it's a better idea to use DOMDocument unless the html code you have doesn't validate.

If you still want to use a expression to get the content in this case it could be done this way:

```
preg_match('@<div id="table-1".*?>([^<]*)</div>@si', $data, $matches);
```

And the content will be on `$matches[1]`.

You can see it working here http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/95f612d313e699add224efca4527417338c7b739

Comment: the content have a few div elements that id "table"
table-1
table-2
table-3

Comment: You can see it working here: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a2156f1f071d27f7522c19bf98d41c6d39845b1b

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1d4d13944084007da82b317d9d866293bcb50fcc i want to get the first content

Comment: OK, I've updated the answer with this new data. Hope it helps

Comment: i dont know why but not working. can u edit table-1 to id="table(regexp)1" pls

Comment: i think the line is causing